# Query multiple URLs from Google Analytics API using R

Tags: r, google-analytics

I got quite a big set of URLs (> 8.500) I want to query the Google Analytics API with using R. I'm working with the [googleAnalyticsR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleAnalyticsR/googleAnalyticsR.pdf) package. The problem is, that I am indeed able to loop through my set of urls, but the dataframe created only returns the total values for the host-id for each row (e.g. same values for each row).
Here's how far I got to this point:

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(lubridate)

#Authorize with google
ga_auth()
ga.acc.list = ga_account_list()
my.id = 123456

#set time range
soty = floor_date(Sys.Date(), "year")
yesterday = floor_date(Sys.Date(), "day") - days(1)

#get some - in this case - random URLs
urls = c("example.com/de/", "example.com/us/", "example.com/en/")
urls = gsub("^example.com/", "ga:pagePath=~", urls)

df = data.frame()

#get data
for(i in urls){
              ga.data = google_analytics_4(my.id,
              date_range = c(soty, yesterday),
              metrics = c("pageviews","avgTimeOnPage","entrances","bounceRate","exitRate"),
              filters = urls[i])
  df = rbind(df, ga.data)}
```

With the result of always receiving the total statistics for the my.id-domain in each row in the dataframe created (own data):

[Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxrxs.png)

Anyone knows of a better way on how to tackle this or does google analytics simply prevent us from querying it in such a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're getting is normal: you only queried for `metrics` (`c("pageviews","avgTimeOnPage","entrances","bounceRate","exitRate")`), so you only get your metrics.

If you want to break down those metrics, you need to use `dimensions`:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

In your case you're interested in the `ga:pagePath` dimension, so something like this (untested code):

```
ga.data = google_analytics_4(my.id,
              date_range = c(soty, yesterday),
              dimensions=c("pagePath"),
              metrics = c("pageviews","avgTimeOnPage","entrances","bounceRate","exitRate"),
              filters = urls[i])
```

I advise you to use the [`Google Analytics Query Explorer`](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) until you get the desired results, then port it to R.

As for the number of results, you might be limited to 1K by default until you increase `max_rows`. [There is a hard limit on 10K from the API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_size), which means you then have to use pagination to retrieve more results if needed. I see some examples in the R documentation with max=99999999, I don't know if the R library automatically handles pagination beyond the first 10K or if they are unaware of the hard limit:

```
batch_gadata <- google_analytics(id = ga_id,
start="2014-08-01", end="2015-08-02",
metrics = c("sessions", "bounceRate"),
dimensions = c("source", "medium",
"landingPagePath",
"hour","minute"),
max=99999999)
```

Comment: yes, I found that one too after asking the question. Managed to successfully execute the query by now, by simply looping through
 seq_along(urls). Should have known that... Thanks for answering anyways.

Comment: You're welcome. I added a comment about the maximum number of results. Don't forget to upvote + accept the answer if it's useful :)

Comment: You don't have to worry about the API pagination if you are using the `google_analytics_4()` function - just set max_results to -1 and it will get all results.

Comment: @MarkeD: thanks for input, please share reference to source/doc

Comment: Sure I documented it here: https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/v4.html#number-of-results

Comment: But these days use the GA4 Data API, that has the same feature of fetching all results if -1 is used https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/reporting-ga4.html#row-limits